# Vue.js - Toggle clicked icon in v-for generated list

Tags: javascript, list, vue.js, data-binding, toggle

In Vue.js I have generated a list of objects.
I would like to color a 'star' when that specific 'star' is click.

But when I click on a star, every star in the list gets colored.

I've made a dummy fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/t3f0rpqh/21/

Actually, it's going te be a font-awesome icon (but I have same problem here - on icon change, every icon in the list changes, not just the clicked one).

```
 <font-awesome-icon
  :class="{ activeIcon: activeIcon}"
  :icon="icon"
  v-on:click="starLocation(item.id)"
 />
```

I don't know how to bind the star/icon to a specific object or how to color only the clicked star/icon.

Any ideas or solutions?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fix this by adding `activeIcon` property to each todo item and toggle them specifically like:

```
data: {
   todos: [
    { text: "Learn JavaScript", id: "Location4", activeIcon: false },
    { text: "Learn Vue", id: "Location3", activeIcon: false },
    { text: "Play around in JSFiddle", id: "Location2", activeIcon: false },
    { text: "Build something awesome", id: "Location1", activeIcon: false }
  ]
}
```

and the  update `starLocation` method like:

```
starLocation(id) {
  try {
     var todo = this.todos.find(t => t.id === id)
     todo.activeIcon = !todo.activeIcon;
  } catch (error) {
    alert(error);
  }
}
```

and finally update your template like:

```html
<p 
  @click="starLocation(item.id)"
  :class="{ activeIcon: item.activeIcon}"
  :key="item.id"> STAR
</p>
```

[**Working Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/ak1dnjo0/1/)